# Android Studio: package does not exist though autocompletion knows the classes

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle

**Abstract:** Android Studio does not Recognize the packagename of a package that I imported via .jar file, though it does know its classes

**What I have done:**
I have built a .jar file from some source files executing the command `jar cf jar-file input-file(s)` ([see Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)) in windows command prompt. I want to use the classes that are packed in that jar for a project in android studio. Therefore, I added a libs folder to my app folder and copied the .jar in there.

Furthermore, I added the dependencies in the app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/CERMIT.jar')
}
```

**The problem:** When I try to import a class from the package with a statement like:

```
import com.hsulm.pfischer.cermitprototype.PackageName.SpecificClass;
```

it says *cannot resolve symbol 'cermitprototype'* and when compiling it throws an *error: package com.hsulm.pfischer.cermitprototype.Controller does not exist*.

**The weird thing:** When I start typing in the Editor, e.g. `Specif` it does want to autocomplete it and if I allow it then it gives me `com.hsulm.pfischer.cermitprototype.PackageName.SpecificClass` so I guess It knows the classes but it does not know the package.

**Additional info:** The .jar file contains multiple packages with multiple classes, respectively and a manifest file. I already tried restarts, gradle syncs and other stuff I found on stack overflow.

---

### Edit:

I've fixed my problem by not building my jar via command prompt but using NetBeans. I guess the reason might have been some ugly dependency issues between classes that were just ignored.